# why keyHolder.getKey() return null

Tags: java

I try to save person in db with jdbc template the person table have an id, name and emotional state so we should generate the id with the keyHolder object for jdbc support the current code save the data in the table but with id null

```
private final String insertSQL =
    """
    insert into PEOPLE ( name , emotional_state ) 
    VALUES ( ? , ? )  
    """ ;

var declaredParameter = List.of(new SqlParameter( Types.VARCHAR , "name") ,
                                new SqlParameter(Types.INTEGER ,"emotional_state")) ;

var pscf = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory( insertSQL ,declaredParameter);
pscf.setReturnGeneratedKeys(true);
pscf.setGeneratedKeysColumnNames("id");

var psc = pscf.newPreparedStatementCreator(List.of(name, index));
KeyHolder kh = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
this.jdbcTemplate.update(psc, kh);
```

Comment: Could you please explain little

Comment: I try to save person in db with jdbc template
the person table have an id, name and emotional state
so we should generate the id with the keyHolder object for  jdbc support 
the current code save the data in the table but with id null

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you call `kh.getKey()` *before* the update and thus before the key is actually generated:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update(psc, kh);

var newId = Objects.requireNonNull(kh.getKey()).longValue(); // here it should be non-null
```